# C SDL Object movement flow

Tags: c, sdl

I just started with SDL and made a small square moving around on a window. 
I used DL_GetKeyboardState, and got it moving kind of smoothly. However, just when I start moving it one direction by holding down one key, it moves a bit, stops, then move like I want. This messes up the smoothness. My best guess is that it waits for a doubleclick from the mouse, but im not sure. Any suggestions?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   SDL_Window *window;
   SDL_Renderer *renderer;
   SDL_Event event;

   SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
   window = SDL_CreateWindow("Yelda!", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1600, 1200, 0);
   renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

   const Uint8 *state;
   int run = 1;
   int xpos=300;
   int ypos=300;
   int projectileYPos;
   int projectileXPos;
   int loop;
   int lanceLength = 10;

   while(run)
   {
      while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
      {
         state=SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

         if(state[SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE])
            run=0;
         if(state[SDL_SCANCODE_W])
            ypos-=10;
         if(state[SDL_SCANCODE_S])
            ypos+=10;
         if(state[SDL_SCANCODE_A])
            xpos-=10;
         if(state[SDL_SCANCODE_D])
            xpos+=10;

         SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
         SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
         SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255 ,255);
         SDL_Rect rect = {xpos, ypos, 20, 20 };
         SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
         SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

         SDL_Delay(20);
      }
   }

   SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
   SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
   SDL_Quit();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `SDL_PollEvent` loop iterates on each event, so you're updating/drawing for each event happens in system. Basically if i'm moving mouse intensively, your code will try to draw each movement, event if it happened quite a time ago (drawing takes time, especially with vsync, plus forced delay). This loop should be used to gather events; updating and drawing should be performed outside of event loop (in top-level `while(run)`).

Comment: this line: `int main(int argc, char * argv[])` (and because neither parameter is used in the posted code) will cause the compiler to raise two warnings about the unused parameters: `argc` and `argv[]`.   Suggest changing the main function signature to: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SDL wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState) says that you should use `SDL_PumpEvents()` to update the keyboard state array.

And indeed, if we

- remove the `while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))` loop (not its contents) as it's unneeded,
- move `state=SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);` before the `while(run)` loop (the address of the array "will be valid for the whole lifetime of the application", so it always returns the same pointer), and
- only call `SDL_PumpEvents()` inside the loop,

then the movement is smooth.

Comment: Actually, `SDL_PollEvent` calls `SDL_PumpEvents`.